# Command gg=G (to indent lines) has no effect in vi[m] on Linux RH

Tags: indentation, vi

I would like to indent lines in files (SQL files, XML...),
and in spite of all that I searched and tried, for some reason
on my Linux servers the command gg=G does nothing (all my lines
keep their first character stuck against the left part of my
terminal...), but displays the message "X lines indented" anyway !

Under Windows where I use gvim it works perfectly.

What does it depend on ? My shiftwidth is well set to 8,
I don't know what else I should check... (some config file
maybe ?, no idea)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set `set nocompatible` and `filetype plugin indent on` in your `.vimrc`. Open your XML file and enter `:set filetype?`. Vi(m) should recognize your file now as XML file (if it does not, tell Vi(m) that the currently open file is an XML file by specifying `:set filetype=xml`). Try to indent your source code now with `gg=G`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message.
Unfortunately the behaviour is the same, even by specifying what you advised me to do. The .vimrc file is located in my home/.vim directory right ?
When doing `gg=G`, it keeps displaying "X lines indented", but nothing gets indented at all...

Comment: Your `.vimrc` under Linux is usually located under `~/`, which is `/home/yourusername`. Does vim recognize your filetype (what happens if you enter `:set filetype?`)?

Comment: It displays indeed `filetype=xml` !

Comment: And -not sure whether really relevant- this /usr/bin/vim is the 7.2.411 of Bram Moolenaar on RH Server release 6.5 Santiago...

Comment: OK *solved* !, I had put this .vimrc file under the ~/.vim directory, I've moved it to my home now, and many things have changed in vim's behaviour now (amongst other things `gg=G` now does  its job).
Thanks  a lot !

Comment: You're welcome. I'd appreciate it if you would accept the answer :)